This post claims that the Puranas and Itihasas aren't considered as the Fifth Veda. I'm really confused. Please tell me that how much accurate is it?
https://unitedhindufront.quora.com/I-will-mention-a-reason-why-we-should-reject-Puranas?ch=10&oid=174130946&share=8d5ad02f&srid=uE1MjW&target_type=post
This is the link where the claim is made. I'm really confused with it. So isn't it true the Puranas and the Itihasas have authority.? Please clarify it.

Among all Hindu denominations, only Arya Samaj rejects the authority of Itihasas & Puranas, because they don't support their version of a formless God. They also don't recognise the authority of ancillary Vedic literature like the smrtis, dharmasutras, grihyasutras, shrautasutras & pariaisthas. They don't even recognise the Upanishads, Aranyakas & Brahmanas among the Vaidika corpus. And among the Vaidika samhitas, they don't even recognise those samhitas the were not studied by their founder (notably the Taittiriya samhita). And it is difficult to refute the Arya Samaj's opinions on all texts.
